# Cache slow animation?

Tags: animation, performance, cache

Let's say I have an animation that my computer can only process at an incredibly slow rate (A forest, for example).

Is it possible to cache the animation so I can work with it (and only have to recompute modified elements) or must I slog through it, possibly for hours, every single time?

Comment: Do you need to see it in the viewport? If not, just hide it. Or you can mask parts of it with the Mask Modifier and vert groups. If these are subsurfed Mesh objects, disable SubSurf for the Viewport. If you only need to see the locations, display just the bounding boxes. By chipping away at things you don't need to see in the Viewport, you can speed up your Viewport's performance.